# running a fastify route periodically (via cron)

Tags: cron, fastify

I would like to run a particular `fastify` route periodically. There is [fastify-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-cron) but I can't figure out if I can use that to call a route from within `fastify`. To summarize, given a route as below, I would like `https://my/server/greeting` to be called every midnight.

```js
fastify.get('/greeting', function (request, reply) {
  reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using that plugin you can use the [`inject` method](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Testing/#benefits-of-using-fastifyinject), used to write tests typically:

```
import Fastify from 'fastify'
import fastifyCron from 'fastify-cron'

const server = Fastify()

server.get('/greeting', function (request, reply) {
  reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
})

server.register(fastifyCron, {
  jobs: [
    {
      cronTime: '0 0 * * *', // Everyday at midnight UTC
      onTick: async server => {
        try {
          const response = await server.inject('/greeting')
          console.log(response.json())
        } catch (err) { console.error(err) }
      }
    }
  ]
})

server.listen(() => {
  // By default, jobs are not running at startup
  server.cron.startAllJobs()
})
```

This is needed because you need to generate e request/response object to run your handler.